# Easeljs: "createjs.Ticker.paused = true" not working

Tags: vue.js, createjs, easeljs

I can't get my animation to pause. I'm using createjs CDN inside vue-cli, trying to make my animation pause at the click of a pause button. I think my setup is okay, because if I replace "createjs.Ticker.paused = true" with "createjs.Ticker.framerate = 1000" in my code below, everything works as expected, but with the former, it has no effect at all. What am I missing?

```
// a method inside a Vue component

controlPlaying(state) {
  if (state == 'play') {
    createjs.Ticker.paused = false;
  }
  else if (state == 'pause') {
    createjs.Ticker.paused = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Ticker.paused does not actually stop animations, its just a flag you can use in your code. https://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html#property_paused

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, if anyone's interested.

There's a variable in the HandleComplete() function called exportRoot.
I put exportRoot in data() as undefined, and then called it from elsewhere with the "this" keyword.

My function ended up looking like this:

```
controlPlaying(state) {
    if (state == 'pause') {
      this.exportRoot.paused = true
    }
    else {
      this.exportRoot.paused = false
    }
  }
```